# select second input on new dynamic added tablerow

Tags: jquery

I'm having problem binding an keyup delegated event on my second input in table
the html. What I want is to bind keyup event to all second inputs in all new table rows. Is it possible?

```
<button id="myButton">Add New Row</button>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td>This is a static row.</td>
    <td><input type="text">
    <td><input type="text">
</tr>
</table>

$("#myButton").click(function () {
var newRow = '<tr><td>dynamic row</td><td><input type="text"><td><input type="text"></tr>';
$('#myTable tr:last').after(newRow);
});

$('#myTable').on('keyup', 'td input:eq(0)', function (event) {
alert('keyup!!!!');
```

Comment: Did you omit the closing `</td>` tags only in the code given, or is your code actually missing those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to target second input so it means you need to  target that td in which second input is in this case it is third td of the tr:

```
$('#myTable').on('keyup', 'tr td:eq(2) input', function (event) {
alert('keyup!!!!');
```

if you want to skip the first row as well which is not added dynamically then:

```
$('#myTable').on('keyup', 'tr:gt(0) td:eq(2) input', function (event) {
    alert('keyup!!!!');
```